# Node packages seems to be doing nothing

Tags: node.js, foreman, forever

I'm running a little Socket.io & Express app on an Ubuntu server and I'm trying to use forever module.

However it seems that it doesn't matter which package I install nothing seems to be happening. I've run

```
sudo npm install  forever -g
```

On install I am getting this message:

> npm WARN engine hawk@0.10.2: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.25","npm":"1.3.10"}

However typing the function forever start app.js just returns to the next line.

```
$:/home/app$ forever start app.js
$:/home/app$
```

Typing which forever returns

```
/usr/local/bin/forever
```

I seem to be getting similar issues for nodemon and foreman, I have no idea why. Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: what if you use ```npm install forever  -g```

Comment: Sorry I made a type i used `sudo npm install  forever -g`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not to sound like a hater but I stopped using forever because they stopped developing it. It has a few issues specifically if you launch an app with it in the startup process you can't see the process to terminate or restart.

Try nodemon, it works best for me and has most of the same options. I know this isn't the answer you were looking for but I hope you'll avoid the same issues I ran into. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

The warning you get happens because of hard dependencies on node 0.8, but it's customary to just ignore them. Just to try, I installed forever on a fresh Ubuntu 14.04 and got a lot of warnings

```
npm WARN engine hawk@0.10.2: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.29","npm":"1.4.14"})
npm WARN engine hawk@0.10.2: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.29","npm":"1.4.14"})
npm WARN engine hawk@0.10.2: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.29","npm":"1.4.14"})
npm WARN engine sntp@0.1.4: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.29","npm":"1.4.14"})
npm WARN engine cryptiles@0.1.3: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.29","npm":"1.4.14"})
npm WARN engine boom@0.3.8: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.29","npm":"1.4.14"})
npm WARN engine hoek@0.7.6: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.29","npm":"1.4.14"})
npm WARN engine sntp@0.1.4: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.29","npm":"1.4.14"})
npm WARN engine cryptiles@0.1.3: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.29","npm":"1.4.14"})
npm WARN engine boom@0.3.8: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.29","npm":"1.4.14"})
npm WARN engine hoek@0.7.6: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.29","npm":"1.4.14"})
npm WARN engine sntp@0.1.4: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.29","npm":"1.4.14"})
npm WARN engine cryptiles@0.1.3: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.29","npm":"1.4.14"})
npm WARN engine boom@0.3.8: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.29","npm":"1.4.14"})
npm WARN engine hoek@0.7.6: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.29","npm":"1.4.14"})
```

but after that, if I call the forever help screen

```
forever -h
```

it displays normally.

Are you executing forever in the same path that your app.js is?
What happens if you call `forever list` after running forever start?
What user are you running forever as? 
Are you sure that running node app.js runs normally?

Comment: Hi, My directory is /home/app/app.js running `nodejs app.js` runs perfectly. (However I can't do `node app.js`). I'm trying to run my forever in the same directory as my app currently and `forever -h` appears to do nothing. I'm using my user(not root) to run the app.

Comment: What about forever -h ?

Comment: forever -h returns nothing `joshy@*:/home/app$ forever -h 
joshy@*:/home/app$`

Comment: Weird. Can you try calling it with the absolute path?

Comment: Typing `joshy@*:/home/app$ /usr/local/bin/forever -h` seems to do exactly the same.

Comment: Try reinstalling it as root, or installing locally in your app dir. I'm out of ideas

Comment: I had a similar issue on my host - running with the absolute path fixed it. For example, this would start index.js in my home directory using node production mode, as the forever module is installed locally (shared host, root access not available); `NODE_ENV=production ~/node_modules/forever/bin/forever start ~/index.js -nouse-idle-notifications`

Comment: Just tried doing this and seems to do exactly the same, I've also tried installing it locally.  No idea if this has anything to do with it but node doesn't exist on this machine only nodejs